# Populate a normal single column combobox with all data from two columns in two different tables

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, excel-tables, listobject

This is the case that i really didn't find neither in this website nor anywhere else:

I have a combobox "Numbers" on my VBA user form. I want to populate it with data from column 1 of table "Names" plus the data from column 1 of table "Families". Both tables are on the same sheet "Sheet2".

I would also like my combobox to not show the duplicate values (in worksheet table columns i want to keep the duplicates).

I would like to put the code under the event of Userform Initialize.

P.S: Again, to emphasize; This is not a multiple column combobox but just a normal combobox with data from two tables.

***Updated: I tried two solutions:

1-Unionrange,

2- loop separately through each range and AddItem command. None is working and I still see only the first range in my combo.

Comment: You'll need to create a custom solution, but this function will get you the data from a specified column, the example shows how to remove duplicates. https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().data()

Answer (score 1):

I don't like referring to tables in VBA, so I wrote a proposition that should work basing on the range.

If you would like to have a code referring to ListObjects, please check here: [VBA: How to refer to columns using table headings so I can use that column in a cell reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612518/vba-how-to-refer-to-columns-using-table-headings-so-i-can-use-that-column-in-a)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    
    Numbers.Clear
    
    lastRow = Worksheets("mdList").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, After:=Range("A1")).Row 'in after pot Names table 1st cell
    
    For Each rng In Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A" & lastRow) 'Names table range
    
        Numbers.AddItem md.Value
    
    Next md
    
    lastRow = Worksheets("mdList").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, After:=Range("A1")).Row 'in after pot Families table 1st cell
    
    For Each rng In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lastRow) 'Families table range
    
        Numbers.AddItem md.Value
    
    Next md
End Sub
```

Code activates when the form is opened.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Bart, I tried with ranges and it works fine. But I do need to have tables as my supervisor wants it (Maybe he thinks its better in tables). I wait for other answers as well

Comment: np, but you can adjust the code to work on Tables via the link I posted above.

Answer (score 1):

### Populate Combo Box With Unique Values From Table Columns

[image]

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_initialize()

    Dim wsNames(): wsNames = VBA.Array("Sheet2", "Sheet2")
    Dim tblNames(): tblNames = VBA.Array("Names", "Families")
    Dim tblColumns(): tblColumns = VBA.Array(1, 1)
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lo As ListObject, rg As Range, Data, rVal
    Dim n As Long, r As Long, rCount As Long
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(wsNames)
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(wsNames(n))
        Set lo = ws.ListObjects(tblNames(n))
        Set rg = lo.ListColumns(tblColumns(n)).DataBodyRange
        rCount = rg.Rows.Count
        If rCount = 1 Then
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
        Else
            Data = rg.Value
        End If
        For r = 1 To rCount
            rVal = Data(r, 1)
            If Not IsError(rVal) Then ' not an error
                If Len(CStr(rVal)) > 0 Then ' not blank
                    If Not dict.Exists(rVal) Then
                        dict(rVal) = Empty
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next r
    Next n
    
    If dict.Count = 0 Then ' only errors and blanks
        Numbers.Clear
    Else
        Numbers.List = dict.Keys
    End If
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I may, I would like to answer my own question since nowhere such an issue is addressed properly and that simple:

To populate a combobox from two different tables on the same sheet. combobox should not show the duplicates.

The code is actually simple:

```
Private Sub UserForm_initialize()


    Dim cloc As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = sh.ListObjects("Names").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
    
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng2 =sh.ListObjects("Families").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
    
    
Numbers.List = Sheets("sheet2").ListObjects("Names").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.value

 '''''''''''to add the other range (first column of the second table)'''''''''''

 For Each cloc In rng2
Numbers.AddItem cloc.value
 Next cloc 

 ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''avoid duplicates'''''''''''''''    
 For x = 0 To Numbers.ListCount - 2
     For j = Me.Numbers.ListCount - 1 To x + 1 Step -1
     If Numbers.List(x) = Numbers.List(j) Then 'repeated
         Numbers.RemoveItem (j)
    End If
   Next j
 Next x

 End Sub
```